# How do VPN servers/clients avoid routing their own remote connection packets through themself?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, route, tun

I am trying to conceptualise how networking works under the hood for linux VPNs which use TUN interfaces.

My current best guess is as follows (please correct me):

1. Connection established to remote client/server.
2. TUN interface created and brought up
3. Routing table updated to set default gateway to the TUN interface

But wouldn't the packets destined for the remote client/server end up going into the TUN interface and forming a loop of sorts? How do VPN systems solve this? What is the gap in my understanding?

Comment: The default gateway won't be vai TUN, I suppose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that with purely destination-based routing this is a problem, if the destinations you are reaching through the tunnel overlap with routing needed for tunnel establishment, etc....

The way I have usually seen this done, and done it myself on various routers, is to use policy routing :

- The router acting as a VPN endpoint keeps its default route pointing to the Internet through its ISP link
- It also has a Policy Route with a source-based rule saying that traffic coming from the subnets behind it, whatever their destination, should be sent through the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

With destination based routing it's not hard either.

The way I usually see is to load a route to the VPN server specifying the pre-existing gateway and interface and distance (really routing priority) set to 1. The VPN's default route would always have a distance of at least 2.

Comment: Note: If the gateway is shared with other users, and capable of port forwarding, this leaves a security hole where connections to another user's forwarded port on the gateway won't go through the VPN.

Comment: True, but it's hard to make that mistake by accident because DNS resolution now passes through the VPN so you can only reference the gateway by IP; asking for its name yields its TUN IP.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a system with 1 physical adapter: enp2s0.

It's routing table might start out as all traffic goes out enp2s0.

Once the system connects to a VPN, a TUN interface (tun0) is initialized and the VPN updates the routing table:
All traffic destined to VPN server address on port X (VPN server address and port) goes out enp2s0. All other traffic goes through tun0.

Of course a VPN doesn't have to route all traffic. For instance, I have set up VPNs before where only traffic that would go to a certain private subnet goes through the VPN so normal internet traffic would be unchanged. How you do this changes based on the VPN program.